# Javascript stop & start console log

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to complete a challenge that asks.

Create a function that takes a message and a number as parameters, and logs the message to the console by the time.

```js
var displayLog = function Container(param) {
  var message = 'any string'; // Local message variable
  var timeCount = '10'; // Local time count variable

  setInterval(function getLoggeddemo(message, timeCount) {
    console.log(message);
    return getLoggeddemo;
  }(), timeCount);

  function myStopFunction() {
    clearInterval(myVar);
  };
}



var mixBut = document.getElementById("mixBut");

mixBut.addEventListener("click", Start);

function Start() {
  displayLog.setInterval();
}

function Stop() {
  displayLog.myStopFunction();
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="mixBut" value="Start" />
```

Comment: Sounds like a cool little challenge. What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: I can't the last piece of JS to function how I would click which is the start and stop function. I don't think I'm referencing the stop function and interval functions correctly

Comment: well you do not store the interval's id...

Comment: Have you [checked your console?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/getting-started-with-javascript/714/using-console-log) You seem to be trying to call a function which doesn't exist. Also, the function you're passing to `setInterval` isn't being passed. You're calling it immediately. Get rid of the `()` on the end.

Comment: I've removed the (), It looks like I'm calling the setInterval wrong it was giving me an error displayLog.setInterval is not a function in the console so I know i'm wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var displayLog  = {

    message : 'any string', // Default local message variable

    timeCount : 1000, // Default local time count variable => equal to 1second

    myVar : undefined, //at first is undefined,see myStartFunction

    setSeconds : function(number_of_seconds){
         this.myStopFunction();//first stop previously event if existing 
         this.timeCount = number_of_seconds * 1000;
    },

    setMessage : function(message){
         this.message= message;
    },

    myStartFunction : function(){
         this.myVar=setInterval(function(){
               console.log(displayLog.message);
          }, displayLog.timeCount);
    },
    myStopFunction:function(){
        clearInterval(this.myVar);
    }
 }

 var mixBut = document.getElementById("mixBut");
 var c = 0;
 mixBut.addEventListener("click", toggleStartStop);

 function toggleStartStop(){
     if(c%2==0)
           displayLog.myStartFunction();
     else 
           displayLog.myStopFunction();
     c++;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I think I'm almost there, I keep getting an error with the message variable, Unexpected identifier. I'm confused because I thought it was declared correctly

Comment: @khalebrucht22 see my new answer, i 've improved it and simplified the code. Remember that timeCount = 1000 actually is 1 second, because the time passed as argument in setInterval must be expressed in milliseconds

Comment: Thank you almost perfect, I think the input button can't stop once the log starts.

Comment: @khalebrucht22 the button as you coded starts the displayLog. Now by just counting how many times the button has been pressed we can toggle start/stop log state